# Why is circular motion "simple harmonic" when there is no restoring force?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

While this question seems similar to [Is uniform circular motion an SHM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146477/), the answers there appear to contradict [Berg & Stork (2004)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Physics_of_Sound/4FpgQgAACAAJ?hl=en).

Berg & Stork first state that simple harmonic motion (SHM) requires a linear restoring force.  And that's apparent with things like a pendulum or a mass on a spring.  However, they then describe uniform circular motion as SHM even when there's no restoring force, e.g., a mathematical point moving uniformly in a circle.  So is the restoring force not really a requirement for SHM?  Is all that's needed to call it SHM the fact that you can describe its motion with a sine wave (which you can do for either x or y in uniform circular motion)?

Comment: "*However, uniform circular motion is also described as SHM even when there's no restoring force.*" Citation, please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is uniform circular motion an SHM?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146477/)

Comment: "Citation, please" ... 
I saw in "The Physics of Sound" by Berg & Stork, 3rd ed., ,p. 6:  
"Uniform circular motion, viewed from a distant point in the plane of the motion, is SHM...." 
True, it doesn't actually say "no restoring force," but the discussion refers to just a point moving in a circle (not a physical object with a central force).

Comment: Thank you. Agreed that the projection of UCM on a perpendicular plane is indistinguishable from SHM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the role of the "restoring force" there is the cartesian component of the centripetal force. The whole force causes the body to move in circle, the component causes the cartesian coordinate to change as sine function of time.